# Dynamically create table colmun into checkboxes

Tags: php

I have table which contains different permissions. Currently i am render all those permsion columns into check boxes manually. Like this

```
global $con;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `permissionsinpage` where `ETPK` = $id"; //chk allow  project name
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
    $no_result = mysql_num_rows($result); // total rows

    echo "ID,Name,Switch,MembersList, Self Category List, Allow Projects,Verify Proj,WhiteBoard,Chk Emp Proj Days,
    Chk Proj Days,Permissions,Main Menu,WhiteBoard_EmpDetail,Entry_WhiteBoard,Proj_StatusEdit,Ger_StatusReport,
    Switch_request, Get Switch Request, Project QuestionAnswer, Allow All Task Finished Request Received, AllowDeadLineInternalView, AllowDeadLineExternalView,
    AllowITComplainsNotInStockPanel, AllowITComplainsPendingOrInprogressPanel, AllowAllITComplainsEdit, AllowEditViewOwnITComplains";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "----//------";
        echo $row['ETPK'];echo",";
        $name = GetEmpName($row['ETPK']);
        echo $name;echo",";
        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="switch"';
        if ($row['switch'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="MemberNames"';
        if ($row['MemberNames'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="selfCategoryList"';
        if( $row['selfCategoryList'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="AllowProjects"';
        if ($row['AllowProjects'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="VerifyAllowProjects"';
        if ($row['VerifyAllowProjects'] ==1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="WhiteBoard"';
        if($row['WhiteBoard'] ==1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="ChkEmpProjDays"';
        if( $row['ChkEmpProjDays'] ==1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="ChkProjDays"';
        if($row['ChkProjDays'] ==1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="permissionPage"';
        if( $row['permissionPage'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="MainMenuTop"';
        if( $row['MainMenuTop'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="WhiteBoard_EmpDetail"';
        if( $row['WhiteBoard_EmpDetail'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="Entry_WhiteBoard"';
        if( $row['Entry_WhiteBoard'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="Proj_StatusEdit"';
        if( $row['Proj_StatusEdit'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="Ger_StatusReport"';
        if( $row['Ger_StatusReport'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="RequestForSwitchEmployee"';
        if( $row['SwitchRequest'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="GetSwitchRequest"';
        if( $row['GetSwitchRequest'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="ProjectQuestionAnswer"';
        if( $row['ProjectQuestionAnswer'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";


        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="AllowAllTaskFinishedRequest"';
        if( $row['AllowAllTaskFinishedRequest'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";


        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="AllowDeadLineInternalView"';
        if( $row['AllowDeadLineInternalView'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";


        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="AllowDeadLineExternalView"';
        if( $row['AllowDeadLineExternalView'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="AllowITComplainsNotInStockPanel"';
        if( $row['AllowITComplainsNotInStockPanel'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="AllowITComplainsPendingOrInprogressPanel"';
        if( $row['AllowITComplainsPendingOrInprogressPanel'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="AllowAllITComplainsEdit"';
        if( $row['AllowAllITComplainsEdit'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">,";

         echo '<input type="checkbox" id="AllowEditViewOwnITComplains"';
        if( $row['AllowEditViewOwnITComplains'] == 1)
            echo "checked";
        echo">";
```

As you can see that i am manully adding even checkbox. Is there anyway to short this code and generate the diesred checked checkbox dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

1. You should not be using `mysql_` functions anymore as they are deprecated.
2. Whether you upgrade to `mysqli_` or `PDO` is up to you, but you should be using a prepared statement.
3. By declaring a lookup / translation array which stores database table column names as keys and output labels as values, you can control all of the variable bits of text from a single source.  This will make managing your script much easier and avoid many points where typos/inconsistencies may be difficult to locate.
4. If `GetEmpName()` is executing another query, then you should be using a JOIN in your posted query to avoid performing separate/iterated queries.

My suggestion with some basic debugging check to make your transition to mysqli smoother:

**The lookup array:**

```
$columnsLabels = [
    'ETPK'                                     => 'ID',
    'switch'                                   => 'Switch',
    'MemberNames'                              => 'MembersList',
    'selfCategoryList'                         => 'Self Category List',
    'AllowProjects'                            => 'Allow Projects',
    'VerifyAllowProjects'                      => 'Verify Proj',
    'WhiteBoard'                               => 'WhiteBoard',
    'ChkEmpProjDays'                           => 'Chk Emp Proj Days',
    'ChkProjDays'                              => 'Chk Proj Days',
    'permissionPage'                           => 'Permissions',
    'MainMenuTop'                              => 'Main Menu',
    'WhiteBoard_EmpDetail'                     => 'WhiteBoard_EmpDetail',
    'Entry_WhiteBoard'                         => 'Entry_WhiteBoard',
    'Proj_StatusEdit'                          => 'Proj_StatusEdit',
    'Ger_StatusReport'                         => 'Get_StatusReport',
    'RequestForSwitchEmployee'                 => 'Switch_request',
    'GetSwitchRequest'                         => 'Get Switch Request',
    'ProjectQuestionAnswer'                    => 'Project QuestionAnswer',
    'AllowAllTaskFinishedRequest'              => 'Allow All Task Finished Request Received',
    'AllowDeadLineInternalView'                => 'AllowDeadLineInternalView',
    'AllowDeadLineExternalView'                => 'AllowDeadLineExternalView',
    'AllowITComplainsNotInStockPanel'          => 'AllowITComplainsNotInStockPanel',
    'AllowITComplainsPendingOrInprogressPanel' => 'AllowITComplainsPendingOrInprogressPanel',
    'AllowAllITComplainsEdit'                  => 'AllowAllITComplainsEdit',
    'AllowEditViewOwnITComplains'              => 'AllowEditViewOwnITComplains'
];
```

**Processing:**

```
$sql = "SELECT " . implode(',', array_keys($columnsLabels)) . " FROM permissionsinpage WHERE ETPK = ?";

if (!$stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) {
    echo "Prepare Syntax Error";
} elseif (!$stmt->bind_param("i", $id) || !$stmt->execute() || !$result = $stmt->get_result()) {
    echo "Statement Error";
} elseif (!$row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "No data found for Id: {$id}";
} else {
    echo implode(',', $columnLabels) , "<br>";
    foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
        if ($column == 'ETPK') {
            $rowOutput[] = "----//------{$value}";
            $rowOutput[] = GetEmpName($value);
        } else {
            $rowOutput[] = "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"{$column}\"" . ($value == 1 ? ' checked' : '') . '>';
        }
    }
    echo implode(',', $rowOutput);
}
```

- I am assuming that `ETPK` is the table's primary key and is unique -- ergo there will either be zero or one row produced by the query.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to consider using **prepared statement** and not using `mysql_` since it has been deprecated.

Second thing, you may wanna use `SHOW COLUMNS` instead of creating any bulk arrays or typing the name of each column.
A clean code for that:

```
$columns = mysqli_query($con, 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM `permissionsinpage`');
while($column = mysqli_fetch_array($columns)) $fields[] = $row['Field'];
```

**So your code will look like:**

```
$columns = mysqli_query($con, 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM `permissionsinpage`');
while($column = mysqli_fetch_array($columns)) $fields[] = $row['Field'];

$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM `permissionsinpage` where `ETPK` = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows === 0) exit('No rows');

echo implode(', ', $fields);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '----//------'.$row['ETPK'].','.GetEmpName($row['ETPK']).',';
    foreach($fields as $field){
        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="'.$field.'"'.($row[$field] == 1 ? ' checked':'').'>,';
    }
}
$stmt->close();
```